# Java - No consigo que se visualice listado de archivo random y tiene registros guardados

Tags: java, random

Primero, antes de la parrafada, muchas gracias por la ayuda. Mi problema es el siguiente:

No consigo que se muestren los datos guardados en un archivo random en un método listado() de una clase Alumno. Los datos están bien grabados ya que en otros métodos como consultas() sí se ven sin problema. Las condiciones a cumplir serían: se listarán el dni, nombre, dos apellidos, las
tres notas y la nota media (si el alumno tiene alguna nota suspensa y la media da superior a 4,5 se visualizará un 4) de todos los alumnos, al final de cada página (pantalla), se listará el numero de aprobados y suspensos que aparecen en cada pantalla y al final el número total de alumnos listados, el número de aprobados y el número de suspensos visualizados en dicho listado.

El método lo tengo planteado de la siguiente manera (utilizo la clase Teclado), se muestran todos los System.out.print sin problema pero no los datos que deberían mostrarse con mostrarDatos():

```
void listGeneral() throws IOException {
    Alumno a = new Alumno(0, "", "", "", "", ' ', 0, "", 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Teclado t = new Teclado();
    boolean fin = false;
    final int LINEAS = 5;
    int cp = 0, cl = LINEAS + 1;
    int aprobadosPagina = 0, suspensosPagina = 0;
    int totalAlumnos = 0, totalAprobados = 0, totalSuspensos = 0;
    RandomAccessFile fich = new RandomAccessFile(ruta + "alumnos.dat", "r");
    do {
        while (!fin && cl < LINEAS) {
            if (a.getNumero() != 0) {

                if (a.calcularMedia() >= 4.5) {
                    a.mostrarDatos(3);
                    aprobadosPagina++;
                    totalAprobados++;
                    totalAlumnos++;
                    cl++;
                } else {
                    a.mostrarDatos(3);
                    suspensosPagina++;
                    totalSuspensos++;
                    totalAlumnos++;
                    cl++;
                }

            }
            fin = a.leerDeArchivo(fich);
        }
        System.out.println("\n\nAprobados en la página " + cp + ": " + aprobadosPagina);
        System.out.println("Suspensos en la página " + cp + ": " + suspensosPagina);
        aprobadosPagina = 0;
        suspensosPagina = 0;

        if (cl == LINEAS) {
            System.out.println("\n\tPulse <Intro> para continuar....");
            t.leerSalto();
        }

        if (!fin) {
            System.out.println("\n\t\tLISTADO GENERAL\t\tPag.: " + (++cp) + "\n\t\t===============\n");
            System.out.println("DNI\t\tNombre\t\tApellido1\t\tApellido2\t\tNota1\t\tNota2\t\tNota3\t\tMedia");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            cl = 0;
        }
    } while (!fin);
    fich.close();

    System.out.println("Total alumnos listados: " + totalAlumnos);
    System.out.println("Total aprobados: " + totalAprobados);
    System.out.println("Total suspensos: " + totalSuspensos);
    System.out.println("\n\n\t\tFIN DEL LISTADO \n");
    System.out.println("\n\tPulse <Intro> para continuar...");
    t.leerSalto();

}
```

El método mostrarDatos() es el siguiente:

```
void mostrarDatos(int t) {   //REVISAR BIEN LAS COSAS QUE VA A MOSTRAR CADA CASO.
    switch (t) {
        case 0: //para listado entre límites (o aprobados o suspensos). OJO PARA SUSPENSOS: que tengan al menos una nota suspensa, no es necesario que tengan las 3 suspensas.
            System.out.println(dni+"\t"+nombre+"\t"+apellido1+"\t"+apellido2+"\t\t"+nota1+"\t\t"+nota2+"\t\t"+nota3);
            break;
        case 1: //para modificaciones.
            System.out.println("DNI.........................: " +dni);
            System.out.println("1.-Nombre...................: " +nombre);
            System.out.println("2.-Apellido 1...............: " +apellido1);
            System.out.println("3.-Apellido 2...............: " +apellido2);
            System.out.println("4.-Sexo.....................: " +sexo);
            System.out.println("5.-Edad.....................: " +edad);
            System.out.println("6.-Ciclo....................: " +ciclo);
            System.out.println("7.-Curso....................: " +curso);
            System.out.println("8.-Nota 1...................: " +nota1);
            System.out.println("9.-Nota 2...................: " +nota2);
            System.out.println("10.-Nota 3..................: " +nota3);
            break;
        case 2:  //consultas y bajas.
            System.out.println("DNI......................: " +dni);
            System.out.println("Nombre...................: " +nombre);
            System.out.println("Apellido 1...............: " +apellido1);
            System.out.println("Apellido 2...............: " +apellido2);
            System.out.println("Sexo.....................: " +sexo);
            System.out.println("Edad.....................: " +edad);
            System.out.println("Ciclo....................: " +ciclo);
            System.out.println("Curso....................: " +curso);
            System.out.println("Nota 1...................: " +nota1);
            System.out.println("Nota 2...................: " +nota2);
            System.out.println("Nota 3...................: " +nota3);
            break;
        case 3: //para listado general.
            System.out.println(dni+"\t"+nombre+"\t"+apellido1+"\t"+apellido2+"\t\t"+nota1+"\t\t"+nota2+"\t\t"+nota3+"\t\t"+calcularMedia());
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Que quiere decir que no se ve bien?? si no muestra nada, es porque las variables estan vacias... estas usando siempre la misma clase o clases distintas???

Comment: si cl = LINEAS + 1 entonces cl < LINEAS de entrada es false... raro... eso es por no debuguear...

Comment: Sí, cl < LINEAS de entrada es false a propósito para que no entre en ese bucle y acabe por imprimir primero la cabecera System.out.println("\n\t\tLISTADO GENERAL\t\tPag.: " + (++cp) + "\n\t\t===============\n");   y que luego al ponerse cl a 0 ya sí entre y vaya imprimiendo los registros con el método mostrarDatos(3);, el caso es que no sale nada... pero entiendo que están bien grabados los datos porque otros métodos del programa sí los imprimen.

Comment: ok.. y vuelvo a preguntar, esas variables, tienen algo???

Comment: Hola sptr, bienvenido, pregunta, en que clase esta el método **mostrarDatos()**, podrías agregar el esqueleto de las dos clases involucradas?.